# How do I plot a dotted circle with outwards pointing vectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've already plotted a dotted circle. Every dot represents a pedestrian, where each of them should also have a velocity. Thats why I want to plot a vector pointing outwards for every pedestrian representing its velocity.
I also need the coordinates of every pedestrian and their velocities, because I want to be able to change their speed. 
[Example image of the desired circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPODu.jpg).

I plotted the circle with the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pdb
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r = 0.5
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)

plt.gcf().gca().plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe try plt.quiver ?

Comment: @BlueRineS I did try it with plt.quiver, but that wasn't successful since I don't know how to specify the "ending points" of the vectors.

Comment: Set up a regular vector, like [0, 1] and rotate it about the z axis using the Z rotation transformation. Once you have the rotated vectors you can plot them by offsetting toward their starting position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a quiver with the x and y coordinates as vectors, `ax.quiver(x,y,x,y)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r = 0.5
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)

ax.plot(x, y, 'ko')
ax.quiver(x,y,x,y)


plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You require some math.

Let u be the unit vector in the horizontal direction:

```
u = np.array([1, 0])
```

The rotate the vector for as many data points that you have according to the corresponding angle theta:

```
 def rotate_z(theta):
     R =np.array([
         [np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
         [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
     return R
```

Now for all your data points you can:

```
 vecs =[]     
 for i in range(len(theta)):
     R = rotate_z(theta[i])
     vec = R @ u  # matrix multiply
     vec = vec + np.array([x[i], y[i]])
     vecs.append(vec)
```

Now you have al your vectors ready for plotting (I think you can use plt.quiver(..) !